# Return values with matching conditions in r

Tags: r, subset

I would like to return values with matching conditions in another column based on a cut score criterion. If the cut scores are not available in the variable, I would like to grab closest larger value. Here is a snapshot of dataset:

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
scores.a <- c(512,531,541,555,562,565,570,572,573,588)
scores.b <- c(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
data <- data.frame(ids, scores.a, scores.b)
> data
   ids scores.a scores.b
1    1      512       12
2    2      531       13
3    3      541       14
4    4      555       15
5    5      562       16
6    6      565       17
7    7      570       18
8    8      572       19
9    9      573       20
10  10      588       21

cuts <- c(531, 560, 571)
```

I would like to grab `score.b` value corresponding to the first cut score, which is `13`. Then, grab score.b value corresponding to the second cut (`560`) score but it is not in the score.a, so I would like to get the score.a value `562` (closest to `560`), and the corresponding value would be `16`. Lastly, for the third cut score (`571`), I would like to get 19 which is the corresponding value of the closest value (`572`) to the third cut score.

Here is what I would like to get.

```
       scores.b
cut.1  13
cut.2  16
cut.3  19
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a rolling join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data.table(cuts = cuts), .(ids = ids, cuts, scores.b), 
          on = .(scores.a = cuts), roll = -Inf]
#   ids cuts scores.b
#1:   2  531       13
#2:   5  560       16
#3:   8  571       19
```

---

Or another option is `findInterval` from `base R` after changing the sign and taking the `rev`erse

```
with(data, scores.b[rev(nrow(data) + 1 - findInterval(rev(-cuts), rev(-scores.a)))])
#[1] 13 16 19
```

Comment: this works great @akrun, always thanks for your quick response!

Comment: The `findInterval` option is neat, though it will rely on the data being sorted I believe. My attempt was similar - `data$scores.b[match(seq_along(cuts), findInterval(data$scores.a, cuts))]`

Comment: @thelatemail That looks better.  You could add as a separate solution as this is switching the arguments

Comment: @thelatemail looks like you posted the same answer as me in the comments above.  Let me know if you post this solution and I'll remove mine

Comment: hi @akrun, if I make a change in the statement above as this below, what would be your suggestion: "If the cut scores are not available in the variable, I would like to grab the closest larger value second cut and closest smaller value the third cut score. I'd like to get: ``13, 16, 18`` instead of ``13,16,19``.

Comment: yes I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882916/subset-values-with-matching-criteria-in-r

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't remove the other columns, but this illustrates correct results better

```
df1 <- data[match(seq_along(cuts), findInterval(data$scores.a, cuts)), ]
rownames(df1) <- paste("cuts", seq_along(cuts), sep = ".")

> df1
       ids scores.a scores.b
cuts.1   2      531       13
cuts.2   5      562       16
cuts.3   8      572       19
```