# Subset values with matching criteria in r

Tags: r, recode

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570555/return-values-with-matching-conditions-in-r) but this one is slightly different.

I would like to return values with matching conditions in another column based on a cut score criterion. If the cut scores are not available in the variable, I would like to grab closest larger value for the first and second cut, and grab the closest smallest value for the third cut. Here is a snapshot of dataset:

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
scores.a <- c(512,531,541,555,562,565,570,572,573,588)
scores.b <- c(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
data <- data.frame(ids, scores.a, scores.b)
> data
   ids scores.a scores.b
1    1      512       12
2    2      531       13
3    3      541       14
4    4      555       15
5    5      562       16
6    6      565       17
7    7      570       18
8    8      572       19
9    9      573       20
10  10      588       21

cuts <- c(531, 560, 571)
```

I would like to grab `score.b` value corresponding to the first cut score, which is `13`. Then, grab score.b value corresponding to the second cut (`560`) score but it is not in the score.a, so I would like to get the score.a value `562` (closest `larger` to `560`), and the corresponding value would be `16`. Lastly, for the third cut score (`571`), I would like to get 18 which is the corresponding value of the closest `smaller` value (`570`) to the third cut score.

Here is what I would like to get.

```
       scores.b
cut.1  13
cut.2  16
cut.3  18
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data %>% 
   mutate(cts = Hmisc::cut2(scores.a, cuts = cuts)) %>% 
   group_by(cts) %>% 
   summarise( mn = min(scores.b),
              mx = max(scores.b)) %>% 
   slice(-c(1,4)) %>% unlist() %>% .[c(3,4,6)] %>% 
   data.frame() %>% 
   magrittr::set_colnames("scores.b") %>% 
   magrittr::set_rownames(c("cut.1", "cut.2", "cut.3"))

      scores.b
cut.1       13
cut.2       16
cut.3       18
```

Comment: thanks @jyjek, I received an error like this ``Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) : slice only accepts one expression``. do you have any thought where that would be coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
data %>% 
mutate(cuts_new = cut(scores.a, breaks = c(531,560,570, 1000), right = F)) %>% 
group_by(cuts_new) %>% summarise(first_sb = first(scores.b)) %>% 
ungroup()
```

results in:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  cuts_new    first_sb
  <fct>          <dbl>
1 [531,560)         13
2 [560,570)         16
3 [570,1e+03)       18
4 NA                12
```

Comment: Thanks @akash87 for your solution!