# Apply different filters and subsequently calculate means

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I am using dplyr to filter a dataframe, and calculate afterwards the means of the subset above each row.

```
data.example <- mtcars %>%
 filter(mpg >= 12) %>%
 arrange(mpg) %>%
 mutate(mean.mpg = round(rev(cummean(rev(mpg))),2))
```

I am interested in the first value,    `data.example$mean.mpg[1]` , in this case **20.74**.
I need to repeat this for different values, for example:

```
mpg>=20 (result is 25.48);  
mpg>=25;  
mpg<12;  
mpg<25;  
12<mpg<25, etc.,
```

Changing the filter value is not time efficient. I found [Subset values with matching criteria in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882916/subset-values-with-matching-criteria-in-r)

```
data.example2 <- mtcars %>%
 arrange(mpg) %>%
 mutate(mean.mpg = round(rev(cummean(rev(mpg))),2))

cuts <- c(12,20,25)
setDT(data.example2)[data.table(cuts = cuts), .(ids = disp, cuts, mean.mpg),
```

I could apply the above for mpg larger or equal than the cut (mpg>=12, etc.) but **this won't work when the cuts aim for values smaller than** (mpg<12, etc.).

The idea behind is to do some kind of `filter(mpg >= 12 | mpg <12 | between(mpg, 12, 25))` and obtain a value for each subset, but I do not know if this is possible.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible results - a loop and an map option.

First some filter options:

```
filter_vec <- c("mpg > 12", 
                "mpg > 20", 
                "mpg > 12 & mpg < 20",
                "mpg < 12",
                "mpg < 25")
```

1. **Loop**

```
# half empty dataframe for the results
df <- data.frame(condition = filter_vec,
                 mean = NA_real_)

for(x in filter_vec) {
  mean_value <- mtcars %>% 
    filter(eval(str2expression(x))) %>%
    summarise(mean.mpg = round(mean(mpg, na.rm = T),2))
  
  df[which(x == filter_vec), "mean"] <- mean_value
}
```

Output

```
            condition  mean
1            mpg > 12 20.74
2            mpg > 20 25.48
3 mpg > 12 & mpg < 20 16.59
4            mpg < 12 10.40
5            mpg < 25 17.79
```

2. **purr:map_df**

```
filtering <- function(x) {
   mtcars %>% 
    filter(eval(str2expression(x))) %>%
    summarise(result = round(mean(mpg, na.rm = T),2)) %>%
    add_column(condition = x)
}

map_df(filter_vec, filtering)
```

Output

```
  result           condition
1  20.74            mpg > 12
2  25.48            mpg > 20
3  16.59 mpg > 12 & mpg < 20
4  10.40            mpg < 12
5  17.79            mpg < 25
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tamtam. Both solutions worked perfectly well. I like the map option a bit better because I found it easier to read.
Some homework for me reading about eval(str2expression(x))